# Unable to get the values of enum in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

In rails 4, I have created an enum called books which is

```
enum books_category: {
  horror: 1,
  mystery: 2,
  drama:  3
}
```

I have a column in the database called Books where I populated it using a csv file. My database attributes are name and books_category. Now when I upgraded to rails 5, books_category attribute of database is directly mapping to the string instead of integer. For example, previously books_category consists of 1 after upgrading it's saving the string "horror". How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ways.

1) create a **mode**l which *saves* **business_categorie**s in it.

**or**

2) when you retrieve record which is storing horror, you can pass it to the model like

**my_model = Model.find_by("business_categot = ?","horror")
Model.books_category[my_model.books_category] # Returns the integer value**

Comment: I want to save the integer value rather than querying the database and finding the integer value. Is it possible?

Comment: before saving it have a query and have integer value store in one variable and then save data using that value.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you are missing a colon after books_category. The code should look like:

   ```
   enum books_category: {
     horror: 1,
     mystery: 2,
     drama:  3
   }
   ```
2. Please edit your question to include the datatype of `books_category` attribute.
3. You can change the value either using strings or ints

   ```
   book = Book.last
   book.books_category = 1
   book.save!
   => book.books_category = "horror"

   book = Book.last
   book.books_category = 'drama'
   book.save!
   => book.books_category = "drama"
   ```

   Please note that Rails always returns the string value even though they are saved in integer datatype.
4. You can get the hash of all `books_categories` by calling

   ```
   Book.book_categories
   => {"horror"=>1, "mystery"=>2, "drama"=>3}
   ```

   And the keys and values by calling

   ```
   Book.book_categories.keys
   => ["horror", "mystery", "drama"]
   ```

   and

   ```
   Book.book_categories.values
   => [1, 2, 3]
   ```
5. Finally, you can get a list of all the objects(books) having the category of `horror` with

   ```
   Book.horror
   => Book Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."books_category" = ?  [["books_category", 1]]
   ```

   As you can observe from the query, it uses integer to search through the Books.
6. If you really want the values of your enum, consider using [Enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) gem. It is simpler and offers much more flexibility

Further Reading: https://hackhands.com/ruby-on-enums-queries-and-rails-4-1/